# OneDrive Linux not synching shared folders

Tags: linux, onedrive

I installed OneDrive as described on this page: [https://github.com/skilion/onedrive](http://github.com/skilion/onedrive)

Synchronization of files works like a charm.
Be aware that default (no parameters) synchronize and exit

However I am unable to get shared files in my`~/OneDrive` folder.

I do not see this option: `go to the Shared files list, right click on the folder you want to sync and then click on "Add to my OneDrive"`
 Is it supposed on the one-drive-website?

(The files are shared by another person with me. On Windows there is another folder in the home directory next to the OneDrive root folder) .. is it supposed to be like this?

Note: it is an Office365 account.

Answer (score 3):

What's your OneDrive account, personal Microsoft account or Office 365 work/school account?

The **Add to my OneDrive** option isn't available when:

- You're signed in with a work or school account.
- You've already added the folder to your OneDrive, or you have more than one folder selected. (You can't add multiple folders at the same time.)
- The item you're trying to add isn't a folder. Add to my OneDrive isn't available for individual files or for collections of files such as albums.

For other details about sync shared folders in OneDrive, you can read: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-and-sync-shared-folders-to-onedrive-8a63cd47-1526-4cd8-bd09-ee3f9bfc1504

Comment: It is an Office 365 account. I assume that's considered a work account. Thanks for pointing that out. Sad though that it is not available to synch shared folders then :(

Answer (score 0):

The 'skilion' client does not reliably support Office 356. Also the 'skilion' code appears to have been abandoned and contains many other issues that have not been fixed. It contains defects that put you at risk of data loss and corruption.

If you wish to use the latest code which contains numerous fixes and enhancements you need clone & build from here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

This fork supports:

- State caching
- Real-Time file monitoring with Inotify
- File upload / download validation to ensure data integrity
- Resumable uploads
- Support OneDrive for Business (including Office 365)
- Shared folders (OneDrive Personal)
- SharePoint / Office 365 Shared Libraries
- Desktop notifications via libnotify